# How to calculate the below values for Oracle and SQL Server databases

Tags: bandwidth, utilization

How to calculate the below values for Oracle and SQL Server databases.

1. Replication Bandwidth Utilization (in %)
2. Replication Queue Size
3. Replication Latency